# Moving Files and Keeping Duplicates

Tags: windows, batch-file, movefile

I'm trying to move files and keep duplicate file names by appending (1) to one of the duplicate files.

I'm using

```
cd /D "source directory"
move *.JPG "target directory"
```

which doesn't solve the problem. Can someone please help?

Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: You can't do that from the command line. Windows Explorer does it for you with specialized code, but it's not built in to any of the Windows command line tools.

Comment: Yes, you can code it yourself. I'm sure if you search here using **[batch-file] move files rename duplicates** you can find code to do so. Your question was about using move.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want. We dir and search for all `.jpg` files in the source folder, then check if it exists, if it does, append a number using a counter, if it does not exist, we just move it..

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "source=D:\source\"
set "dest=D:\destination\"
set /a cnt=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /S /B /A-D "%source%*.jpg"') do for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('dir /B "%%a"') do if exist "%dest%\%%b" (
        set "ext=%%~xa"
        set "fname=%%~na"
        if exist "%dest%\!fname!(!cnt!)!ext!" (set /a cnt=!cnt!+1)
        set /a cnt=!cnt!+1
        move "%%a" "%dest%\!fname!(!cnt!)!ext!"
) else move "%%a" "%dest%\%%b"
```